# Antminer S7 Dual Power Supply

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, mining-setup, antminer, psu

I am planning on powering up Antminer S7 with dual power supply per usermanual (https://shop.bitmain.com/files/download/Antminer%20S7%20user%20guide.pdf) page 4.  It does not say minimum power requirement for PSU1 and PSU2.

Two boards with 950Watt and 1 Board with 850 Watt.

[image]

I plan on using regular power mode without over clocking.  So can it be safe to assume I only need 450 Watt per board and 950 Watt for two board will be just enough?  Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we only need 450 Watts per board and 950 Watts PSU1 and 850 Watt PSU2 worked. Make sure you turn on PSU2 After PSU1 as the S7 manual says.